# Controlling emulator display on Vista, size, time, etc

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm just starting to learn Android doing the Hello World app, and some of the emulator settings are larger than the screen so I can't see the whole thing - WVGA800 and WVGA854. The others (QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432) are OK. And I can't move the displayed emulator or drag the edge. One solution is to use one of the displays that fit, but I figured there should be a better answer.

I tried in Eclipse: Windows | Preferences | Android | Launch | Default em ops
          -timezone "America/Denver" -version -scale .3
to fix the timezone, show the version, and change the scale, and restarted the emulator (Run | Run) but the settings don't seem to change anything. The time is still universal instead of local.

I even restarted eclipse and the emulator, didn't help.

Also, when I Run|Run the Hello World, I have to click the emulator Menu key to get the Hello to display. The em normally displays probably the home screen with the icons.

Everything should be the latest version, I just downloaded it all yesterday.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start the emulator from Window | Android SDK and AVD Manager (from the Eclipse main menu) and set the scale that way. I don't particularly worry about the time zone, since you need to handle all time zones, anyway.

> Also, when I Run|Run the Hello World, I have to click the emulator Menu key to get the Hello to display.

Correct.

> The em normally displays probably the home screen with the icons.

Only on the very first run of an AVD will it go straight to the home screen; subsequent runs go to the keyguard. This is identical behavior to a device (other than the device typically goes through the setup wizard on first run).

Comment: How do you set the scale from the AVD screen? The only way I see is 'Skin' and two overflow the screen? Timezone isn't essential - I just thought there'd be an easy fix. And thanks for the tip about startup.

Comment: @Paul Kinzelman: When you click Start, check the "Scale display to real size" checkbox and fill in the appropriate values.